# upgrade from 15.04 to 15.10 getting compiz segfault

Tags: upgrade, compiz, screen, crash, 15.10

After upgrade from ubuntu 15.04 to 15.10 getting massive screen flicker - system is unusable.  Using the console (ctrl-alt-F1) I noticed dmesg says compiz is abending

```
[  150.423110] compiz[2676]: segfault at 1001a ip 00007f142039e135 sp 00007ffc5bfc8fd0 error 4 in libc-2.21.so[7f142031f000+1c0000]
[  153.569558] compiz[2714]: segfault at ffffffffffd98b80 ip 00007f4462f8e1e1 sp 00007ffd9e82e300 error 5 in libc-2.21.so[7f4462f0f000+1c0000]
[  155.287526] compiz[2762]: segfault at 1001a ip 00007f4f0cb68135 sp 00007ffc6a1531e0 error 4 in libc-2.21.so[7f4f0cae9000+1c0000]
[  156.770911] compiz[2807]: segfault at ffffffffffcfa170 ip 00007f6675a981e1 sp 00007fffc53c4d80 error 5 in libc-2.21.so[7f6675a19000+1c0000]
[  158.249853] compiz[2846]: segfault at ffffffffffd33940 ip 00007f1f513441e1 sp 00007fff98ae6e70 error 5 in libc-2.21.so[7f1f512c5000+1c0000]
```

Should I try doing :

```
sudo unity --reset
```

am using :   AMD graphics card

Comment: And what drivers: open or closed?

Comment: I am using AMD closed drivers ... looks like I will try to cut over to using nouveau from the console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things did not seem to be right after upgrading to 15.10. Compiz crashes every single time when I login. I got this from dmesg:

```
[  323.672731] compiz[18440]: segfault at 7ffe673fbfe8 ip 00007f1e704dc5bf sp 00007ffe673fbff0 error 6 in libc-2.21.so[7f1e7046e000+1c0000]
```

I've tried unity --reset and it did not work, though it really reseted unity, but compiz still crashed. I tried deleting ~/.compiz and ~/.config/compiz-1, but didn't work either

Does it mean something's wrong with libc-2.21.so?

**Update**

I looked into my crash-report and found that it was due to my personalized cursor theme inconsistency. I advise you to look into the crash-report next time next time it pops up or go to /var/crash/ and find the compiz crash report. Look for the word "Stacktrace," and the data underneath may reveal the problem. For me, I have

```
 #1999 0x00007f65c4ed1212 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1
 No symbol table info available.
```

Thus I assumed it's the problem with the cursor theme and it worked.

Hope that works for you :)